# Copy/move the files selected in the ListView to the folder selected via FolderBrowserDialog failed

Tags: c#

help is really needed) In listView2 there is a list of files which, by clicking on button5, should be copied / moved to the folder selected in FolderBrowserDialog.

Here is what it is:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(item.Text)))
                return;
            File.Copy(Path.GetFullPath(item.Text), 
                Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, Path.GetFileName(item.Text)),
                true);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the files are not copied to the folder

Comment: Hi, you might want to check the value returned by Path.GetFullPath(item.Text) and your Path.Combine(...). I bet they do not give valid paths.

Comment: Yes you are right.
Could you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are giving the *wrong path* to your instructions because you are manipulating wrong type of paths.
There are two types of path :

- **Absolute path** : full path to the file, containing drive and all folders to it, pros are you can access the same path from EVERYWHERE
- **Relative path** : path relative to the executable, if exe is located in "C:/Temp", you can access "C:/Temp/foo/bar" by using a relative path like "foo/bar" and it will work since you are in "C:/Temp"

---

In your case, you choose a directory from FolderBrowserDialog which will return an **absolute** path like :

```
folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "C:/users/myname/mydir"
```

Then you will iterate through your list which should contain **absolute** path of your files.

Working with **absolute** paths, you don't need to combine any path, just use them

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.SelectedItems)
{
    if (!File.Exists())
        return;

    File.Copy(item.Text, folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, true);
}
```